# Executing process substitution result as a script

Tags: bash, shell, aria2

I would like to create a temporary shell script, and pass it as a parameter to another script, i.e. a callback hook.  Is it possible to use process substitution for that?

In this example, [aria2c](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html) allows a hook as a parameter. aria2c will call that hook with a few parameters once the page is downloaded.  Ideally, I would like aria2c to call my "virtual" script, without first making any temp files, like so:

```
aria2c \
  --on-download-complete <(echo '#!/bin/sh'; echo 'echo "Called with [$1] [$2] [$3]"') \
  https://aria2.github.io/
```

but as a result i get a permissioning error:

```
Could not execute user command: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

Comment: Because `aria2` uses [`execlp`](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/blob/master/src/util.cc#L2243), I believe it is impossible, and you have to create a temporary file.

Comment: "I would like my script to call aria2c directly" ? Do you mean "I would like aria2c to call my script directly" ?

Comment: @jhnc I meant that I would like aria2c to call a script which does not exist as a file, but rather only as a `/dev/fd`. I clarified the language in the post.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, `aria2c` expects the hook argument to be the **filename of a program** to execute as the callback. However the filename that results from process substitution is not such a program; process substitution returns the **filename of a named pipe**.

You cannot do what you want without creating *any* files. However, a single static helper program and an exported bash function gets close:

**/my/odc/helper**

```
#!/bin/bash
__aria2c_odc_helper_function "$@"
exit
```

use as something like:

```
__aria2c_odc_helper_function(){
    echo "Called with [$1] [$2] [$3]"
}
export -f __aria2c_odc_helper_function

aria2c --on-download-complete /my/odc/helper \
    https://aria2.github.io/
```

Comment: A way safer option would be to just export a function rather then a variable if using bash anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, that's true.

Comment: Would this approach work if aria2c is called from python rather than bash?  E.g. is it possible to add a shell function as an env var to the context of aria2c subprocess call?

Comment: Probably not (I'm not sure one can export bash functions through a process that isn't bash), but a variant of the `eval` approach from original version of this answer would probably work (ie. export an environment variable that can be read by the subprocess).